# How to change subsite group access request?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, groups, sub-site

I am in a company where we are trying to organize our SharePoint documents sites by subsidiaries - services (There is one sub-site per service).

In my example the subsidiary is "France" (root) and the service "MA" is a sub-site.
We don't want each service to access other service's documents so I disabled inherited permissions in each sub-sites and they have their own sub-site groups.
"MA_LECTURE" is a sub-site group.

I'd like, and am struggling to allow, one sub-site group to manage access requests.
Access request configuration says that only members of the root default's group are allowed to accept or refuse access requests.

[image]

But I don't want to add people to the root default group because I want to restrain root access and modifications.

Is there a way to change the sub-site group used to manage access request?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Do you want to control who will receive access requests for sub-site?

Comment: This is Sharpoint on Office 365.
Yes That's it I want to control who will receive access requests for sub-site.
The thing is there is a message (in screeshot) saying that only memebers of my root group will be able to do that.

Comment: While breaking the inheritance from site collection, did you created new groups for your subsite??

Comment: Yes I created groups for subsites , I don't want to add people to the root default group because I want to restrain root access and modifications to others subsites

Comment: If any user requests an access for this subsite and you accepts its request that time you will get an option to which group/permission you want to grant for the user. That time you can add user to the group on sub-site and it will not change anything on site collection level.

Comment: I don't want to be the one that accept the request, that's the point.
I rather want to delegate this action to the subsite admin group (and currently Sharepoint don't let me choose an other group than the default root group )

It's written " ony France-members can allow or refuse access request " , and France members is my default root site group .

Comment: Try following the steps given in my answer below and let me know if you have any difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. At sub-site level, while breaking the permissions from Site collection select the options to **create a new group** and create groups for your sub-site as given below:

   [image]
2. Then go to the home page of your sub-site.
3. Select **Site permissions** from Settings(Gear) icon.
4. Click on **Change sharing settings** under **Sharing Settings**.
5. Toggle **Allow access requests** to show as **ON**.
6. Choose your sub-site owner group under **Choose who will receive access requests for this site** (Check below Image).
7. Click **Save**.

   [image]

**Note**: Replace **Site Name** with your sub-site name.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for this it leads me to the right path I think.
I tried to create a new subsite (and breaking permission during the process) and I got your screen where I can create 3 groups Owner/Members/visitors .

On this subsite the default group that is allowed to manage requests access is the subsite owner group. 

The difference about my existing subsite is that I break inheritance after the subsite was already created, resulting in a lot of root groups permissions on the subsite (and the root owner as default group allowed to manage requests access ) .

Comment: Is there a way on an existing subsite to get the screen where you can define which group should be used for Owners/Memebers/Visitors ? 

I tried to delete all not subsite groups and redifine permission ( Owner-TotalControl / Members-Modification / visitors - readonly ) , but my owner group members are showing under visitors in the document page permission

Comment: So it's ok ! I reactivated inheritance and breaking again and I got the option to redefine defaults groups and now everything is fine ! Thanks !

Comment: Great. Glad it worked for you:)

Comment: If you know a way to get this screen tho, it might help other people that can't reactivate and breaking inheritance. (my library was not that complicated so it has no impact for me to do that but some people might need to redifine theses defaults groups without reactivating/breaking again inheritance ! ) 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage permissions of a site or sub-site you could consider using the [Manage Hierarchy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-gb%252farticle%252fUnderstanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848) group.  As you see the Manage Hierarchy group has the `Manage Permissions` permission.  My answer is based on you using 'broken inheritance' so that each sub-site has unique permissions.

You could trying giving a user in the sub-site `Manage Hierarchy` permissions.  This would allow the user to manage permissions in that sub-site.  You'd then need to find a way to delegate to this group - [this link here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3#bk_enableallow_sponline) looks useful for doing this.

[image: To set up access requests]

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your help, I tried indead to put theses rights but It seems like sharepoint need 3 defaults groups for standard owners/members/visitors and even I have groups corresponding to theses rights, some features are still not available. 

I needed to reactivate and breaking again inheritance like Ganesh suggested to get the option to redefine theses 3 defaults groups ! 

thanks !