# Change group that receives access requests for subsite with unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, groups

I want to change the group that receives access requests for my sharepoint.com subsite which has unique permissions, see screenshot

[image: Access Requests Settings]

I've already read a related question "[How to change subsite group access request?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270077/how-to-change-subsite-group-access-request)" but the answers all begin with breaking inheritance to create unique permissions, and that process sets the group for access control.   But my subsite already has unique permissions.  Discussion in that answer also talks about re-inheriting then breaking back to unique, but that would be very disruptive for my subsite.

What other options do I have to change the group that receives access requests for my subsite which already has unique permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you not create a new owner group when you stop inheriting permissions in the subsite?

If you have not created a new owner group, you can not modify the allow access requests group.

The only way is to delete unique permission the stop inheriting permissions again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As I wrote in the question, I'm looking for other options that don't require deleting unique permissions and then recreating.  Hopefully someone else will have additional suggestions.

Comment: According to my knowledge, there's no OOTB way. Hope someone can help you.